# why does .map() log out the array correctly the first time but say 'undefined' the second time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, next.js, stripe-payments

`

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            const bodyItems = req.body.items;
            console.log(bodyItems)
            
            const renderCartItems = bodyItems?.map( singleProduct => {
                return {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: 'usd',
                        product_data: {
                            name: singleProduct.name
                        },
                        unit_amount: singleProduct.price
                    },
                    quantity: singleProduct.qty,
                }
            })
            console.log(renderCartItems, "mapped")
            
            // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                line_items: renderCartItems,
                
                mode: 'payment',
                success_url: `http://localhost:3000/done`,
                cancel_url: `http://localhost:3000`,
            });
            console.log(session.url)
            res.redirect(303, session.url); 
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
        }
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
        res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    }
}
```

`

this is the error

```
"The `line_items` parameter is required in payment mode."
```

and this is what got consoled out from my consonle.log statments

```
[
  {
    name: 'sped',
    qty: 1,
    price: 5000,
    img: { _type: 'image', asset: [Object] },
    ogprice: 5000
  }
]
[
  {
    price_data: { currency: 'usd', product_data: [Object], unit_amount: 5000 },
    quantity: 1
  }
] mapped

undefined
undefined mapped
```

Anybody know how to fix this problem? It seems to get the right data on the first run, but on the second one it returns undefined. I tried using react strict mode but it still runs twice

Comment: Since you added `Reactjs` in your tag, pls add the react code bcuz react could re-render twice and may cause this problem

Comment: The first undefined in your output is probably the result of `console.log(bodyItems)` - if that is undefined the rest won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back, the log output your shared appears to indicate your `handler` is running twice, once with `req.body.items` as you expect, and once  where that's undefined.

I'd suggest adding logging at the start of `handler` to understand what this extra request is, and also examine your browser network logs to see if the endpoint is being called twice in the client-side code. You might find this is a React error where you're calling your API with unstable data when you don't intend to.